# How to consistently add files to a bundle in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, macos, filesystems

I'm not able to consistently add files to a bundle package. I recall once being able to drag images from one place and right into the bundle in finder, but right now, anything I try to drag into the bundle goes right back to its original location. If I try to copy/paste a file into the bundle the file gets placed at the same level as the .bundle package in Finder.

**How I open the bundle:**

1. In Xcode navigation area, right-click on myBundleName.bundle
2. Select 'Show in Finder'
3. In finder, right-click on myBundleName.bundle
4. Select 'Show Package Contents'

**Question 1:** How to add a file to this bundle?
**Question 2:** Why does it seem that I'm sometimes able to add files and sometimes not?

*Sidenote: I am able to delete files from the bundle.*